# What do you do if you run out of arrows against Phantom Ganon?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

The boss of the Forest Temple keeps going into and out of pictures. On my first playthrough, I couldn't figure out what to do before I ran out of arrows, and I figured it was easier to just reset and try again at that point.

If you run out of arrows and would rather not reset, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you run out of arrows you can actually use the [Hookshot](http://zeldawiki.org/Phantom_Ganon#Strategy), but it's a bit harder to use due to the decreased speed.